# WPF - Avoid duplicate codes to prevent opening the same window twice from one method

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, oop, code-reuse

I have `OpenWindow(Window window)` to showing windows

```
 private void OpenWindow(Window window)
        {
            window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            window.Icon = this.Icon;
            window.Show();
        }
```

and using some other codes to prevent opining the same window twice

```
 private void addStore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                bool isWindowOpen = false;
                foreach (Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
                {
                    if (w is CompanyWindow)
                    {
                        isWindowOpen = true;
                        w.Activate();
                    }
                }
                if (!isWindowOpen)
                {
                    OpenWindow(new StoresWindow());
                }
            }
    
  private void SotreList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool isWindowOpen = false;
            foreach (Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                if (w is CompanyWindow)
                {
                    isWindowOpen = true;
                    w.Activate();
                }
            }
            if (!isWindowOpen)
            {
                OpenWindow(new StoreListWindow());
            }
        }
```

What I need is how can I write **Prevent twice windows opening** codes in `OpenWindow()`?

Comment: You already did that with your isWindow opened? Isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is worked, but I don't want that duplicates. :)

Comment: I would also suggest trying out some MVVM and commands instead of click handlers - you will get lost with more windows and buttons

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicates you can use generics

```
public void OpenWindow<T> () where T: Window, new() {
        var active = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x = >x is T)
        if (active == null) {
            var window = new T();
            window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            window.Icon = this.Icon;
            window.Show();
        }
        else {
            active.Activate();
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
OpenWindow<StoreListWindow>();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I got this Error:
Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint.
in this code line
var window = new T();

Comment: Thanks again, I found the problem by adding the `new()` constraint after the Window: 

`public void OpenWindow<T>() where T : Window, new()`

Comment: @Dlear Ahmad sorry, I have typed that without IDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot, no need to apologize, regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:

```
 private void OpenWindow(Window window)
        {
            foreach (var w in Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                //If the Types of the Windows match,
                if (window.GetType() == w.GetType())
                    //Ends the Method
                    return;
            }

            window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            window.Icon = this.Icon;
            window.Show();
        }
```

Comment: nice solution, but not optimal. New window objects will be created just to check whether they exist.

Comment: another option would be to add a public static bool to the custom window classes, set the bool to true in the constructor, and to false in the deconstructor. Then check if the value is false before creating the window.

Comment: I tried that but the window dose not opened, and the program will not stop after closing the main Window.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an extension method to set a flag whenever it is open and a method to check IsOpen. I mean extension methods on Window.

Or else try to write some logic on.... Application.Current.Windows